# Javascript function to php using parameters

Tags: javascript, php

Good evening,

I have this piece of PHP code :

```
<?php    
function testCopyFile($currentFile, $destinationFile)
{
    copy($currentFile, $destinationFile);
}    
?>
```

Is there a means in my javascript code to call the function and to pass the two parameters?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have any HTML that goes along with this?

Comment: You mean my whole HTML file or just an extract?

Comment: Just the `<form>` part for starters.

Comment: Actually, I don't have any form, what I have is several bootstrap buttons which are calling some scripts - and I would like to embed this new function. Not sure if it is understandable.

Answer (score 0):

No (hint "server side" vs "client side"). All you can do is to make HTTP request to the PHP code (be it GET or POST), and pass arguments in the request. The script you would invoke then be able to call that method.

PS: You are about to invent AJAX :)

Comment: For sure. I am not willing to reinvent the wheel. Thanks for your tolerance and your hint.